# Get running workflow using SharePoint Online REST APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm desperately looking for a way to get the status of a workflow on a list item using the SharePoint REST API. I need to implement it from a workflow and need to make a web service call in order to check if the workflow is stopped or still running on an item.

Is there something similar to this using REST :

```
var workflowInstances = workflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listId, listItemId);
```

Thanks for your help !